# Clearcase Issue

Tags: clearcase

I am responsible for clearcase at my project. I do not have much experience.
My issue is , right now our project structure in cc is a project  with PROD,PV, ST, DV streams as seen here;

[Link to the screenshot](http://img115.imageshack.us/img115/993/cc1hz.jpg)

Now as you can see we have individual stream for each developer under DV stream. The way we deliver code up stream is one by one. Now due to changes in the management, we have to implement in such a way that PARALLEL development is possible. i.e. if there is a bug in Prod and we want to fix it and deliver it back to prod, without delivering the current activities/baselines which are being worked on by different developers, how can we change our cc project to incorporate that?

we want to have something like 
PROD (JAN release)
    -PV (JAN release)
    -ST (JAN, FEB release)
    -DV (JAN, FEB, MAR release)

to manage JAN, FEB, MAR release separately. If we have to fix something in JAN release and do not want to include FEB and MAR releases, how can we do that?

It will be great if you can give us some insight as soon as possible.

Comment: No problem, the "one stream per developer" is a classic mistake. If you have anymore questions, do not hesitate to ask them here ;)

Comment: Link to screenshot is dead/just gives me endless advertisements; without that, it's hard to piucture what you're trying to tell us.

Answer (score 4):

> individual stream for each developer under DV stream

Whoât???? This is SPARTA! (err... no: [madness: this is madness](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDRAhiBtOrQ&hl=fr))

A stream represents a development effort, not a sandbox for a "resource" (i.e. "a developer"). Resources come and go, development tasks stay.
You should have a stream per development line, upon which many developers create their own view.

That way, if you need a parallel development, you only need to create one "brother" stream beside the current one, in order to rebase that bug-fix stream with a baseline from PROD.
So:

```
PROD
  PV
    ST
      DV
  PV-JAN
```

By creating PV-JAN, you create a stream dedicated to small evolutions to the baseline created for JAN.
And you do not have to create all those sub-streams per developer, since it would represent far too many deliver/rebase steps.
The 2 or 3 developers who need to fix anything on PV-JAN create their own view on the *same* stream. They will all participate to the same development effort (fixing bugs for the JAN release of PV)

Comment: Thanks!! That did help confirm my doubts. The structure being used here is something they came up with long before I joined and they are hesitant in changing it..:-(

Regards,
dj