# ClearCase Use branch only until merged

Tags: version-control, clearcase

I am relatively new to ClearCase, and have spent a decent chunk of my time today trying to get my config spec working smoothly.  I keep getting errors with check-outs, check-ins, and merges despite many attempts to fix it...

Our basic working structure is that there is a branch for each phase of the project, and each developer has a working branch.  I want to be able to create my branch for any checkout, and once it has been merged back in to use the latest version for that phase.  I do not really like it, but that is the way we are supposed to do it.

I have tried the following:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * .../my_phase1_working_branch/LATEST
element * .../phase_1/LATEST -mkbranch my_phase1_working_branch
element * /main/LATEST
```

However once I merge files back in, my view will still look at `my_phase1_working`.  As I am supposed to just keep 1 branch for the entire phase I need to constantly manually check and merge the latest changes into my branch, not a reasonable way to operate.
If I remove the `element * .../my_phase1_working_branch/LATEST` then it does not work at all.  I have been spending way too much time on this and I am sure there must be a relatively simple solution...

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and once it has been merged back in to use the latest version for that phase

Then... make a second view, one dedicated to be at the LATEST of that phase.

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * .../phase_1/LATEST
element * /main/LATEST
```

Trying to keep both development effort (one for `phase_1`, and one for `working_branch`) won't be sustainable.

---

Or... since [I don't like one branch per developer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1567308/6309), try to work with one or several developers on a *common* branch representing a coherent development effort for `phase_1`, instead of artificially isolating each contribution in its own branch (which you have then to merge back and force, a *very* slow operation  in ClearCase).

A branch shouldn't be tied to a "resource" (ie a developer), but should be tied to a task (what I called a "development effort").

Comment: This is the way we operated on my previous project, a single branch for groups of developers on a single task, I agree that it is a much more natural flow for the work cycle.  If anyone needed a special sauce or did not want the latest they just used a working label.

Comment: @Prediluted I agree. One stream per task is a much sensible model, which actually apply to many VCS tools, not just ClearCase.